# Puzzled about the behavior of NDSolve (ODE's involving Integrals)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Any idea why `NDSolve` can easily handle the first of these examples, but not the 2nd? I have a system of ODE's involving integrals without closed-form solutions, and keep getting the 2nd error message. The suggested method takes a very long time.

[image: examples 1 and 2]

#### Edit

Here is the code:

```
sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {z'[v] == 1/v*Integrate[Exp[-t]*(1 - Erf[(z[v] - t)/Sqrt[2]]), {t, 0, ∞}],
     z[1] == 1}, 
    {z}, {v, 1, 5}]

sol2 = 
  NDSolve[
    {z'[v] == 
       1/v*Integrate[Exp[-(t - v)^2/2]*(1 - Erf[(z[v] - t)/Sqrt[2]]), {t, 0, ∞}], 
     z[1] == 1}, 
    {z}, {v, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: Please provide the code in a form that can be copied directly from the question into Mathematica.

Comment: Done, sorry & thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the time constraint in the second option below:

```
SystemOptions["NDSolveOptions"]
(*
  {"NDSolveOptions" ->
    {"DefaultScanDiscontinuityTimeConstraint" -> 1.,
     "DefaultSolveTimeConstraint" -> 1.}}
*)
```

For me, I get this for the integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[-(t - v)^2/2]*(1 - Erf[(z[v] - t)/Sqrt[2]]), {t, 0, Infinity}] //
   AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the integral takes too long, longer than the `"DefaultSolveTimeConstraint"`. But wait! Notice the integral sign-- the integral cannot be calculated.  When it is fed to `Solve`, *Mathematica* actually attempts to solve the integral several times:

```
Solve[ 
 z'[v] == 1/v*Integrate[
     Exp[-(t - v)^2/2]*(1 - Erf[(z[v] - t)/Sqrt[2]]), {t, 0, Infinity}], z'[v]] //
 AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it takes way too long for a time constraint of 1 second.  Further, the integral sign means at each step of the `NDSolve`, the integral is going to be calculated symbolically, which will fail, and then numerically approximated.  I'd suggest going straight to `NIntegrate` as follows:

```
rhs[z_?NumericQ, v_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Exp[-(t - v)^2/2]*(1 - Erf[(z - t)/Sqrt[2]]), {t, 0, Infinity}];
sol2 = NDSolve[{z'[v] == 1/v*rhs[z[v], v], z[1] == 1}, {z}, {v, 1, 5}]
(*  {{z -> InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 5.}}, <>]}}  *)
```

[image]

*Addendum:* For completeness, let me mention you can use `SetSystemOptions` to set the time constraint to, say, 100 sec., but that seems inadvisable in this particular case.

One might add that if a symbolic integral can be done, it is probably better to compute it before feeding it to `NDSolve`.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried NIntegrate more primitively, but was getting large errors (compared to if I called the integral a new variable, provided an ODE for it, and integrated by parts until I got sthg mathematica liked better). This seems more promising.